# angularjs using `ng-repeat` scope function not called

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

I am calling a method from the `ng-repeat` iterator. But i am not getting the method called in the scope. any one help me to sort this out?

here is my js :

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.levels = {'title':'Select a Level', item:["Low", "Medium", "Hight"], show:false };
  $scope.stages = ["Open", "Inprogress", "Closed"];
  $scope.colors = ["Red", "Yellow", "Blue"];

  $scope.levelHandler = function ( level ) {
    console.log( level ); //not called
  }

});


app.directive('dropDown', function () {

  return {

    replace:true,
    scope :{
      data:"="
    },
    template : $('#dropdown').html(),
    link:function (scope, element, attrs) {

      var title = element.find('.title');
      var listHolder = element.find('ul');
      var parent = title.add(listHolder);
      var list = element.find('li');

      title.on('click',  function (e) {
         scope.data.show = !scope.data.show;
         scope.$apply();

      });

      parent.add(listHolder).on('mouseleave',  function (e) {
         scope.data.show = !scope.data.show;
         scope.$apply();
      });


    }

  }

})
```

HTML :

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <form name="myform">

      <drop-down data="levels" ></drop-down>

    </form>
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="dropdown">

    <div class="formGroup">
        <h4 class="title">{{data.title}}</h4>
        <ul ng-show='data.show'>
          <li ng-repeat="level in data.item" ng-click="levelHandler( level )" >{{level}}</li>
        </ul>
      </div>

  </script>
  </body>
```

[Live Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/OnpxSrEgvn80isXlIRPg?p=preview)

Comment: Your directive can be done without jQuery. See [this PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/9iA0Mfl57Bt5cFKg8E62?p=preview).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your directive has an isolated scope, therefore you'll need to bind the outside function from the controller into the directive, and it'll work as expected.

here's a working [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/1i2Yif4PCsG94ze5gfzy?p=preview)

```
scope :{
    data:"=",
    func: '='
}
```

template:

```
<drop-down func='levelHandler' data="levels" ></drop-down>
..
<li ng-repeat="level in data.item" ng-click="func( level )" >{{level}}</li>
```

here's a nice [tutorial](http://www.undefinednull.com/2014/02/11/mastering-the-scope-of-a-directive-in-angularjs/) that explains directive scope

Comment: as well i am using number of `scope.$apply();` for each of the eavents. is there a way to minimize it?

Answer (score 1):

You have an isolated scope inside your directive so you can't just refer to values in the scope outside. What you probably want here is to pass the `levelHandler` function into the dfirective:

```
app.directive('dropDown', function () {

  return {

    replace:true,
    scope :{
      data:"=",
      levelHandler: "="
    },
    template : $('#dropdown').html(),
    link:function (scope, element, attrs) {
...
})
```

and then in your html:

```
<drop-down data="levels" level-handler="levelHandler" ></drop-down>
```

an alternative would be to not use an isolated scope at all but just access data through `attrs.data`. This has the disadvantage that if it's an expression you have to evaluate it your self, but it can sometimes be preferable.

BTW, it is usually better to use `ng-click` and `ng-mouseleave` in your template rather than binding the events. That way you never have to worry about calling `scope.$apply()` for yourself.

Comment: I agree, I am going to use no.of drop downs to save time i am trying the `directive`, if you have any better way to re-usable component approach let me know.